# Create an ODataQueryOptions programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, odata

My API currently has some OData endpoints that use generic ODataQueryOptions to recieve an OData query...

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("search")]
public object Search(ODataQueryOptions<MySearchableEntity> options)
{
    return searchService.Search(options);
}
```

`searchService` then traverses the `Expression` of `options.Filter.FilterClause` to build a custom SQL query. It does similar stuff for the order, top and skip parameters.

This is all working fine, but I now need it to parse a query for a dynamic type.

Is it possible to programmatically build an EdmModel and IEdmType etc for the ODataQueryContext, without having a 'real' CLR type backing it up?

The 'type' is well defined in that we have classes describing its shape, but it doesn't exist as a CLR type.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Answering my own question, as I've found the answer.

The `ODataQueryContext` that is used to validate the query accepts a `Type`, but there is an overload that accepts an IEdmType, which in turn can be an `EdmModel`, which is very easy to build in a bunch of different ways.

Docs here:

http://odata.github.io/WebApi/02-01-model-builder-abstract/

http://odata.github.io/WebApi/02-02-model-builder-untyped/

http://odata.github.io/WebApi/02-03-model-builder-nonconvention/

http://odata.github.io/WebApi/02-04-convention-model-builder/

Comment: All the links above go to the same page