# How to alter Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData ODataQueryOptions in Asp.Net Core API

Tags: odata, asp.net-core-webapi

- OData - Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData

  - Version=7.0.1.20718

I am working on Asp.Net core 2.1 Web API and I am using OData. 
How can alter Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData ODataQueryOptions in Asp.Net Core API?

```
 public IQueryable<Product> Get( ODataQueryOptions<Product> options )
    {
          //Alter QueryOptions Here
    }
```

I did the same in **.Net Framework** and Its working but the Same thing is not working in Asp.Net Core 2.1.

```
public ODataQueryOptions<Product> CreateNewQueryOptions(string httpUrlWithODataQueryOptions)
    {
        ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.EntitySet<Product>("Products");
        var edmModel = builder.GetEdmModel();

        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        config.EnableDependencyInjection();

        var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, httpUrlWithODataQueryOptions);
        req.SetConfiguration(config);
        var queryOptions = new ODataQueryOptions<Product>(new ODataQueryContext(edmModel, typeof(Product), req.ODataProperties().Path), req);
        return queryOptions;
    }
```

I have already gone through following threads - 
[Create an ODataQueryOptions programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52663683/create-an-odataqueryoptions-programmatically) 
[How to Instantiate ODataQueryOptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33572659/how-to-instantiate-odataqueryoptions)